# Issue with Woocommerce wc_create_refund

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

We want to create a refund from a webhook but the refunded amount seems to triple the refunded amount.

Below is what we have for the code and this is only triggered once.

```
$order_id = (isset($_REQUEST["order_id"]) && strlen($_REQUEST["order_id"]) > 0) ? intval($_REQUEST["order_id"]) : false;
$amount = (isset($_REQUEST["amount"]) && strlen($_REQUEST["amount"]) > 0) ? floatval($_REQUEST["amount"]) : false;
$reason = (isset($_REQUEST["reason"]) && strlen($_REQUEST["reason"]) > 0) ? $_REQUEST["reason"] : false;
if ($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    if ($order->get_remaining_refund_amount() >= $amount) {
        $refund = wc_create_refund(array(
            'amount' => $amount,
            'reason' => $reason,
            'order_id' => $order_id,
            'refund_payment' => true
        ));
        if (is_wp_error($refund)) {
            if ($refund->get_error_message() == 'Invalid refund amount.') {

                echo 'Refund requested exceeds remaining order balance of ' . $order->get_formatted_order_total();
            } else {
                echo $refund->get_error_message();
            }
        } else {
            echo $refund->get_id();
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Refund requested exceeds remaining order balance of ' . $order->get_formatted_order_total();
    }

}
```

But as you can see from this screenshot below, it seems to triple the refunded value but not sure why

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on why this might happen.

The request comes in as a post http request with a unique key identifier. eg

```
https://example.com/process-refunds/?key=ff5f61b5a9d6ff2a5d7fb9fc815113d4&order_id=1234&amount=100&reason=Testing
```

Comment: Are you calling this via WooCommerce hook or directly?

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress I am calling this directly via an external post request

Comment: Do one thing - try calling the same script in `init` hook and confirm whether its working fine? I didn't find anything wrong with your code. Please let me know if you need full code.

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress testing now

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress issue remains

Comment: I added an answer, can you please confirm whether you have added like that? If yes, can you try refund from plugin like that?

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress tried your answer and still same issue

Comment: Then definitely something wrong with WooCommerce or any of its add-on plugins. Are you using latest WooCommerce version? Can you try disable all plugins other than WooCommerce and try again?

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress done the whole plugin elimination process and narrowed it down to w3 total cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the function in `init` hook (add to your theme's 'functions.php') which working fine for me.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wc_manual_refund' );

function wc_manual_refund()
{
    $order_id = (isset($_REQUEST["order_id"]) && strlen($_REQUEST["order_id"]) > 0) ? intval($_REQUEST["order_id"]) : false;
    $amount = (isset($_REQUEST["amount"]) && strlen($_REQUEST["amount"]) > 0) ? floatval($_REQUEST["amount"]) : false;
    $reason = (isset($_REQUEST["reason"]) && strlen($_REQUEST["reason"]) > 0) ? $_REQUEST["reason"] : false;

    if ($order_id) {
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

        if ($order->get_remaining_refund_amount() >= $amount) {
            $refund = wc_create_refund(array(
                'amount' => $amount,
                'reason' => $reason,
                'order_id' => $order_id,
                'refund_payment' => true
            ));
            if (is_wp_error($refund)) {
                if ($refund->get_error_message() == 'Invalid refund amount.') {
                    echo 'Refund requested exceeds remaining order balance of ' . $order->get_formatted_order_total();
                } else {
                    echo $refund->get_error_message();
                }
            } else {
                echo $refund->get_id();
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Refund requested exceeds remaining order balance of ' . $order->get_formatted_order_total();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: awarded due to the constant assistance

Comment: Thanks @Outsource Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Check condition with get max refund amount. And Ensure your code runs only once by using static variable.

```
static $result;

$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

$max_refund = wc_format_decimal($order->get_total() - $order->get_total_refunded());
    if (!$max_refund) {
      return;
    }

if($result == null){
// Create the refund object
$refund = wc_create_refund(array('amount' => $max_refund, 'reason' => __('Order Fully Refunded', 'woocommerce'), 'order_id' => $order_id, 'line_items' => array()));
wc_delete_shop_order_transients($order_id);

} 
$result = 'code-already-run';
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I will test this today and let you know

Comment: I have tested this, and it does not work. the refund itself is only once but the refunded amount still displays triple